# How to assign and validate arrays to forms in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-formbuilder

My model (`this.profile`) in javascript has a property called `emails`, which is an array of `{email, isDefault, status}`

Then I defined it as below

```
  this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    .... other properties here
    emails: [this.profile.emails]
  });

  console.log(this.profile.emails); //is an array
  console.log(this.profileForm.emails); // undefined
```

in html file I used it as

```
    <div *ngFor="let emailInfo of profileForm.emails">
        {{emailInfo.email}}
        <button (click)="removeEmail(emailInfo)">
           Remove 
        </button>
    </div>
```

If I don't add it in `formGroup` and use it as an array - like below - it's working fine, but then I have a business rule that this array shouldn't be empty and I am unable to set form validation based on length of this

```
  emails : [];
  this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    .... other properties here
  });

  this.emails = this.profile.emails;
  console.log(this.profile.emails); //is an array
  console.log(this.emails); // is an array
```

also I tried using `formBuilder.array` but that one is for having array of controls not array of data.

```
   emails: this.formBuilder.array([this.profile.emails])
```

then my question is how should I bind an array from model to UI and how should I validate the length of array?

Comment: What's the content of `this.emails`? You can use minLength to validate the `formArray` length with the latest versions of Angular.

Comment: this.emails is an array, `[{email:xx,isDefault:false},{email:yy,isDefault:true}]`, how can I define it in formArray and access it in html, because right now the value become undefined?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How should I bind an array from model to UI?

Well, I'd prefer to push all the *emails* from `profile.emails` to the `formArray`, otherwise you'll have the values, but no validation.

> How should I validate the length of array?

You can use the `Validators.minLength(Number)` as any other *control*.

**Demo** code:

**Component:**

```
export class AnyComponent implements OnInit {

  profileForm: FormGroup;
  emailsCtrl: FormArray;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.emailsCtrl = this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.minLength(ANY_NUMBER));
    this.profile.emails.forEach((email: any) => this.emailsCtrl.push(this.initEmail(email)));

    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      // ... other controls
      emails: this.emailsCtrl
    });
  }

  private initEmail = (obj: any): FormGroup => {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      'email': [obj.email], //, any validation],
      'isDefault': [obj.isDefault] //, any validation]
    });
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<div *ngFor="let emailInfo of emailsCtrl.value">
  {{emailInfo.email}}
  <button (click)="removeEmail(emailInfo)">
    Remove
  </button>
</div>
<div *ngIf="emailsCtrl.hasError('minlength')">
  It should have at least {{emailsCtrl.getError('minlength').requiredLength}} emails
</div>
```

**PS1:** Note that the param of `Validators.minLength(param)` *method* must be greater than 1, otherwise it won't validate.

As you can see in [**source**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7b7ae5fe56dd05a28821b5324e7d7863247bacee/modules/%40angular/forms/src/validators.ts#L114) when the **control** is empty it automatically returns null.

Then, to make it work as you expected you could add the `required` *Validator*:

```
this.emailsCtrl = this.formBuilder.array([], Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(ANY_NUMBER > 1)]);
```

And in template:

```
<div *ngIf="emailsCtrl.invalid">
  <span *ngIf="emailsCtrl.hasError('required')">
    It's required
  </span>
  <span *ngIf="emailsCtrl.hasError('minlength')">
    It should have at least {{emailsCtrl.getError('minlength').requiredLength}} emails
  </span>
</div>
```

**PS2:**

I think makes more sense to pass the index of the email that you want to delete in your `removeEmail` *function*, so you willn't have to call `indexOf` to get the index of the *specific* `email`. You can do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let emailInfo of emailsCtrl.value; let i = index">
  {{emailInfo.email}}
  <button (click)="removeEmail(i)">
    Remove
  </button>
</div>
```

**Component:**

```
removeEmail(i: number): void {
  this.emailsCtrl.removeAt(i);
}
```

Take a look at this simple <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YoqdBEo0MihaxdhHH1FV?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working as I was expected, except for validation
While `emailsCtrl.value.length` is 1 and email address are shown in html, but it still has validation error, to clarify I added this to html,         `{{emailsCtrl.value.length}} {{emailsCtrl.errors | json}}` and result in html is `1
        {
  "minlength": {
    "requiredLength": 1,
    "actualLength": 0
  }
}`

Comment: as a workaround I developed a custom validator for emailsCtrl, then the other issue is when I remove an email,customValidator is not called, 
`removeEmail(emailInfo: ContactEmail) 
{
  this.zone.run(() => {
   this.emailsCtrl.value.splice(this.emailsCtrl.value.indexOf(emailInfo), 1);
  });
}` , no matter using or not using `ngZone`

Comment: I ended up with having a customValidation to check the length, and re initializing emailsCtrl on remove

Comment: Hello @RezaRahmati, please take a look at the edit version. I provide some more explanation and examples. Regards :)

Comment: I start using same code as you did, but still not valid, after hours of investigation I found out you are using ng2.4.8 and I am using 2.2.1, so I changed your plunker to 2.2.1 and the issue exists there too, so it seems it was a bug which is fixed in 2.4.8 (http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbokVq1qbzfZI2A1uJop?p=preview) even when you have 2 or 3 emails it keep saying `It should have at least 2 emails` ;)

Comment: @developer033 , thanks for the direction. I have a follow-on question to your example if you're able to help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684564/how-to-populate-a-form-with-array-of-data-in-angular2

Answer (score 6):

This works for me (angular 2.1.2), this approach gives you the flexibility to define a custom validation for your emails:

```
 this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    emails: [this.profile.emails, FormValidatorUtils.nonEmpty]
    // ......
  });

export class FormValidatorUtils {

  static nonEmpty(control: any) {
    if (!control.value || control.value.length === 0) {
      return { 'noElements': true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```