# How to populate a form with array of data in Angular2?

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-formbuilder, formarray

The SO question below helped me setup a formbuilder, proper validation, and a dynamic set of input fields from a formBuilder Array.

[How to assign and validate arrays to forms in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352793/how-to-assign-and-validate-arrays-to-forms-in-angular2)

Note this solution code http://plnkr.co/edit/YoqdBEo0MihaxdhHH1FV?p=preview

Everything works great on a new form, but I get stuck when trying to populate said form from the database.

I'm using the following code and initialValue has multiple emails saved from this form in a previous transaction. All my other form fields work perfectly. I'm just not sure how to operate on an array.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if(this.form && changes['initialValue']){
    this.emails = changes['initialValue'].currentValue.emails;
    this.form.patchValue(changes['initialValue'].currentValue);
    //console.log('emails are now', this.emails);
    //this.emailCtrl = this.fb.array([], Validators.minLength(1));
    //this.emails.forEach((email: any) => this.addEmail(email));
  }
}
```

If I keep the lines commented only the first email in the array shows properly in the form.

If i uncomment the lines and try to refresh the emailsCtrl w/ the new list of emails. I get the following error.

```
ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'emails -> 1 -> email'
at _throwError (forms.js:2385)
at setUpControl (forms.js:2255)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:6606)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:7256)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:7169)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12092)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13598)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13541)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14413)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14354)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.emailCtrl = this.fb.array([], Validators.minLength(1));
this.emails.forEach((email: any) => this.addEmail(email));
```

The FormArray should be `this.emailsCtrl` other than `this.emailCtrl`
   The formArrayName is **emails** and the formControlName is **email**

You can access it based on the name:

```
  this.emailsCtrl = this.form.get('emails') as FormArray;
  this.emails.forEach(email => this.addEmail(email));
```

Comment: ooooh love programming :-p.   So how do I empty it first before I forEach?

It is currently repeating the first email.

Comment: You can use `removeAt(index)` to remove item from FormArray

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. :)